# Let or var in swift loop

Tags: swift, loops, constants, var

Here is a sample of Swift UI code, a simple loop with a "variable" number value being changed.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let a = 1.0
    let a = 2.0 // invalid redeclaration

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach (0..<3) {i in
                var number = i+1 // variable number was never mutated - use let instead
                Text("var \(number)")
                }
            ForEach (0..<3) {i in
                let number = i+1
                Text("let \(number)")
                }
//            ForEach (0..<3) {i in
                //number = i+1 // cannot find number in scope
//                Text("nothing \(number)")
//                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The bizarre thing is that :

- "var number" : a recommandation to use "let" because "there are no change in the value of number"
- "let number" : is OK despite it is in a loop and therefore modified several times

Both work but I am surprised that let (designed for constants) is used and even preferred within a loop. Any explanation ?

Comment: You are creating 3 of those lines not mutating if there is no change to the variables you use a let of you are changing them you use a var

Comment: Nothing bizarre here -- in your first example, you create `number` and never change it after its initial assignment. In the 3rd example, you never define `number`. Maybe you're trying/expecting to mutate `i` during the loop instead of creating a new variable?

Comment: @ lorem ileum: Sure, but in a loop, the value of number is changed several times, no ?

Comment: No. A new variable is created each time through the loop.  Inside if each iteration of the loop, number is not mutated after it is assigned a value.

Comment: No, a new instance is created for each iteration. It’s about scope, `number` only lives inside the loop so when an iteration is done it doesn’t exists anymore

Comment: The scope being "the previous `{` and it corresponding `}`" enclosing the `let someVar` or `var someVar`. So even if it's named also `number`, it doesn't exists in your third "attempt".

Comment: It's not about the loop here. Every variable in Swift that never change its value within the execution is recommended to declare as `let`. The reason is very simple, it helps you to maintain your code and investigate bug better. Let's say you use this `let` within your loop, then you are 100% sure that this variable won't cause any wrong calculation within your code. Even if you accidentally  try to mutate this variable, compiling error will occur, but if you use `var` in this case, and you accidentally mutate it, compiling error won't tell you, and you will end up producing wrong output.

Comment: @all : if I put number=number+1 instead, does the reasoning stands ? Is it the same between ForEach and for the standard SWIFT for ?

Comment: Then it’s an error. var number = number + 1? Nobody does that.

Comment: @ tail for instance when you want to make an accumulation.

Comment: Whatever you are going to do, there are only two possible outcomes; are you going to mutate that variable ? If no, use let : If yes, use var. To be honest, nobody is going to stop you from using var in every situation.

Comment: Not in this case, if you want to mutate the variable it has to exist outside the loop. Everything inside the loop is being recreated when 0,1,2 is created. There is no sharing between them, they are 3 completely different segments of code.

Answer (score 0):

Paradoxes rely on some misunderstanding and therefore make progressing.

Here, the question is : what is the scope with the for(ForEach).
In most languages,  it is all the instructions between the for and its end. Here, **the scope is each instance of the iteration**. Then a let, reserved for constants, is fully adequate since the variable is never modified within each instance of the iteration.

If one wants to cumulate the variable, say number, number must be declared in the environment of the for loop.

Thanks to all who commented.